# Hibernate equivalent of ActiveRecord's has_many :through

Tags: java, hibernate

In Rails it is possible to declare a transitive relation as follows:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :authorships
    has_many :books, :through => :authorships
end
```

Is it possible to do something similar in Hibernate? When I call `author.getBooks()` I want Hibernate to know to join authors with authorships with books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything in Hibernate's mappings that can accomplish this, but you could simply add a `getBooks()` method to your `Author` class that calls the correct method on the `authorships` property:

```
public class Author {
    public Collection<Book> getBooks() {
        if (this.authorships != null) {
            return this.authorships.getBooks();
        }
        return null;    
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the ORM would need to know about a transitive relationship between A and C between B, if you can just set that up in the class on it's own.

Comment: Thanks, that's the workaround I currently have. The problem (and this is probably a different question) is when you add single table inheritance and want to get polymorphic joins based on the class of the association. 

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `@ManyToMany` with a `@JoinTable` to explain how the relationship has to be mapped.

```
@ManyToMany(targetEntity = Book.class)
@JoinTable(name = "authorships",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "author_id")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "book_id")})        
public Set<Book> books;
```